# Prove that the following four statements are equivalent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras

Prove that the following statements are equivalent for a nonzero ring D:

(i) $D$ is a division ring.

(ii) For all $ a, b ∈ D $ with $ a \neq 0 $, the equations $ ax = b $ and $ ya = b $ have unique solutions in $ D $.

(iii) For all $ a, b ∈ D $ with $ a \neq 0 $, the equation $ ax = b $ has a solution in $ D $.

(iv) $ D^{2} \neq 0 $ and $D$ has no right ideals other than $0$ and $D$.

Comment: (iv) $ \Rightarrow $(i) : Let $ 0 \neq a \in D $ then $ aD $ is right idel of $ D $. Either $ aD $ is zero or $ D $. So $ aD = D $...

Since $ D $ has element that 1 there exists $ x \in D $
Such that $ ax=1 $. Thus a has a rıght inverse. But how can I show that a has also left inverse?

Comment: But before everything I'm not sure whether the ring $D$ has an element $1$ because hypothesis says that just $D$ is nonzero ring.

Comment: When you post a question is a good idea to write your attemps and thoughts. Having said that, your idea to prove (iv)$\implies$(i) is right. Just note that you can apply the same reasoning to $x$ and conclude that there is some $y\in D$ such that $xy=1$, thus $a(xy)=a$, which lead us to $(ax)y=1y=a$, so $ax=xa=1$.

Comment: Also, can you help me for (iii) ⇒⇒ (iv) ? 


(iii) ⇒(iv) Since the equation $ax=b$ has a solution in $D$ there exists elements $y$ and $z$ such that $yz≠0$. So $D^2≠0$. Suppose that $D$ has a right ideal $I$ be a nonzero. So we should. Show that $I$ must be equal to $D$. To show this. Let $ a∈I$ and $ b \in D $ so there exists $x∈D$ such that $ax=b$. Since $I$ be a right ideal $b∈I$. So $D⊆I$. And always $I⊆D$ exists. Thus $I=D$ 


But I don't sure this is true?

Comment: And lastly, how can I show that if $D$ is nonassociative algebra then (ii) holds. Because we know that if $D$ is associative algebra then (ii) holds.

Comment: What is your definition of "division algebra"? What does $D^2$ mean? If you're not assuming associativity, then is the definition of ideal still the same as for associative algebras?

Comment: Buse Eralp, one of the assumptions was that $D$ is a ring. A ring is always associative. To many authors (= to all that I approve of ) a ring also always has a $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $D$ is unital and associative. We can show TFAE:

$\rm(i)$. $D$ has two-sided multiplicative inverses for nonzero elements.

$\rm(ii)$. The equations $ax=b$ and $xa=b$ are always solvable when $a\ne0$.

$\rm (iii)$. The equation $ax=b$ is always solvable when $a\ne 0$.

$\rm (iv)$. $D$ has no zero divisors and no nontrivial proper right ideals.

---

$\rm (i)\Rightarrow(ii)$: Given $ax=b$ we may left multiply by $a^{-1}$ to get $x=a^{-1}b$, and similarly we may right multiply $xa=b$ by $a^{-1}$ to get $x=ba^{-1}$, so the equations are solvable.

$\rm (ii)\Rightarrow(iii)$: This is obvious.

$\rm (iii)\Rightarrow(iv)$: Suppose $J$ is a nontrivial right ideal of $D$. Pick $a\in J$ nonzero. Then $ax=1$ is solvable, but we know $ax\in J$, so $1\in J\Rightarrow J=D$.

$\rm (iv)\Rightarrow(i)$. Suppose $a\in D$ is nonzero and consider the right ideal $aD$. Since $aD\ne 0$, we know we must instead have $aD=D$, and thus $ax=1$ for some $x$. Left multiply by $x$ to get $(xa)x=x$, which gives $(xa-1)x=0$, which since there are no zero divisors gives $xa=1$ and so $x$ is in fact a two-sided inverse.

---

Without the assumption of associativity, things go haywire. To begin with, I'm not sure if ideals really make sense, so we'll throw that condition out.

The algebra above showing a right inverse is a left inverse doesn't use associativity, but it does use [flexibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_algebra), a special case of [alternativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_algebra). But without flexibility, it is possible for an element to have distinct left and right inverses.

**Example A**. Consider the "perturbed" quaternions $(\mathbb{H},\bullet)$ in which the basis elements $1,\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$ have the same multiplication table except $\mathbf{i}^2=-1$ is replaced by $\mathbf{i}\bullet\mathbf{i}=-1+\varepsilon \mathbf{j}$.

One may rewrite $\mathbf{j}$ as either $\mathbf{k}\bullet\mathbf{i}$ or $-\mathbf{i}\bullet\mathbf{k}$, collect terms, factor $\mathbf{i}$ out of the appropriate side, and move the minus sign to obtain either of

$$ \begin{cases} (-\mathbf{i}+\varepsilon\mathbf{k})\bullet\mathbf{i}=1 \\
\mathbf{i}\bullet(-\mathbf{i}-\varepsilon\mathbf{k})=1 \end{cases} $$

Thus, $\mathbf{i}$ has distinct left and right multiplicative inverses with respect to $\bullet$.

On the other hand, the $\bullet$ operation has no zero divisors. Write the operation as

$$\mathbf{x}\bullet\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{xy}+\varepsilon x_1y_1\mathbf{j}.$$

(where $\mathbf{xy}$ is usual quaternion multiplication). Set this equal to $0$, move $\varepsilon x_1y_1\mathbf{j}$ to the other side, then take norms of both sides assuming $x_1y_1\ne 0$ and $|\varepsilon|<1$ to get a contradiction.

For finite rings $R$ or finite-dimensional algebras over fields, the absence of zero divisors is equivalent to $ax=b$ and $xa=b$ always being solvable. Both are equivalent to the bijectivity of the left-multiplication-by-$a$ and the right-multiplication-by-$a$ maps (exercise). However, I don't know if these are equivalent otherwise.

**Example B**. Not only may a ring have no zero divisors but have distinct left/right multiplicative inverses, it may have zero divisors even though two-sided multiplicative inverses always exist. This is the case with the 16-dimensional number system called the [sedenions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion).